# Localstorage.setItem() doesn´t work properly

Tags: validation, local-storage, angular5

I have the following `validator` where I check if the `username`contains `admin` in it, then I want to set the `role` to `localStorage` for later use and `return isAdmin: true`.

For some reason most of the times doesn´t write anything to localStorage, and then it does ocassionally which is weird.

Any idea what can be wrong?

```
 import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

    export class AdminValidator {

        static getAdminValidator() {
            return function adminValidator(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {

                // Write code here..
                if (control.value.match(/^admin/)) {
                    localStorage.setItem('role', 'admin');
                    return { isAdmin: true };
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```